# Get document ID of logged user - Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

How can I get document ID (that is automatically generated on registration) of logged user? I don't want uid of current user. I am using Firestore Database in Flutter. What I want:

[image: What i need]

What I get: uid

```
String getDocId() {
  final usersRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
  if (uid != null) {
    usersRef.where('uid', isEqualTo: uid).get().then((querySnapshot) {
      if (querySnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        String docId = querySnapshot.docs[0].id;
        print(docId);
        return docId;
      }
    });
  }
  return "empty -1";
}
```

Comment: Do you mean, you get `”uid”`? Or what?

Comment: yes, I get uid and I want to get document ID of logged user. Not its uid

Comment: A Firebase *user* does not have a documentID - it only has a UID which is assigned to that user when they are created. It's common practice to use the users UID in Firestore to store additional user data. For example you may have a `/users` collection where each document within that collection has a documentId of the users uid. But - you create that, it's not done for you. That makes is convenient as when the user logs in, you will know their uid, and then can directly read any additional data about them from `/users/their_uid/`